# Valgrind and where new/delete/malloc/free are called from?

Tags: valgrind

I'm running valgrind-3.15.0 on an embedded ARM platform with switches:

```
--5484--    --tool=memcheck
--5484--    --track-origins=yes
--5484--    --leak-check=full
--5484--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--5484--    --trace-children=yes
--5484--    --sigill-diagnostics=no
--5484--    --keep-debuginfo=yes
--5484--    --num-callers=500
--5484--    --verbose
--5484--    --verbose
--5484--    --demangle=yes
```

Everyone agrees that debugging information needs to be built into the binary, and I've seen people say use -g, -ggdb, or -ggdb3.  I've tried all 3 with no change in output with regards to the problem.  I am compiling with optimization O1 which I've read should be OK.

I wrote a contrived program to allocate memory, free it, and then write past the end of free'd memory to see what I'd get:

```
==5484== Invalid write of size 1
==5484==    at 0x5EBF6: SpecificObject::Process() (SpecificObject.cpp:98)
==5484==    by 0x10BA1: SSystem::RunSingleSol(unsigned int) (SSystem.cpp:4162)
==5484==    by 0x1162F: SSystem::RunSolution(unsigned int) (SSystem.cpp:3772)
==5484==    by 0x159DB: SSystem::RunMain() (SSystem.cpp:2765)
==5484==    by 0x1E527: SSystem::Enter() (SSystem.cpp:2557)
==5484==    by 0x485F43D: MTask::MTaskEnter(void*) (MTask.cpp:183)
==5484==    by 0x4886E35: ThreadCaller(void*) (WinAbstract.cpp:1562)
==5484==    by 0x4EF0F0F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==5484==    by 0x4C0AF57: ??? (clone.S:86)
==5484==  Address 0x64b9752 is 1 bytes after a block of size 25 free'd
==5484==    at 0x4836D18: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==5484==  Block was alloc'd at
==5484==    at 0x483584C: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
```

In SpecificObject::Process, I have this test code in a switch/case statement (the only other code in this case is a break):

```
char *Crash = new char[25];
for(i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++)
    Crash[i] = 0xFF;

delete []Crash;

// use after free.
Crash[26] = 10;
```

Line 98 is the "Crash[26]=10" which makes sense since that is the overwrite and the allocation via new is only a few lines above it.

However no matter what I do, I cannot get new nor delete to show me anything except what's above, I see other people have tracebacks from where exactly new/delete/malloc/free was called from. For example, from some other random example on Stack Overflow, someone said they see:

```
==9700==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9700==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9700==    by 0x403D6F: get_all_system_info (kernel.c:118)
==9700==    by 0x547DE99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==9700==    by 0x57873FC: clone (clone.S:112)
```

As you can see, it shows that malloc was called by get_all_system_info(), etc... (again that's just a random example of what I'm trying to see)

How do I obtain this information?

Comment: Basic problem is that valgrind only gives you one stack trace per report item, and for an invalid write, that is a trace of where the write occurred, not a trace of where the malloc occurred.

Comment: Please try with a more recent Valgrind. I would also recommend keeping the Valgrind options to a minimum (you may need `--trace-children=yes` but probably not any of the others).

Comment: `--track-origins=yes` should cause information on where the memory comes from the be displayed (local variable or allocation with malloc/new). However I can't help much with such an old version of Valgrind.

Comment: I'll see what I can do - it's on an embedded platform that I have some input into, so I can see if I can have it upgraded.